# Automatic pagebreaks between several samepage environments

Tags: page-breaking, samepage

I am using the [mathpartir package](http://cristal.inria.fr/~remy/latex/) to display some inference rules. I defined my own LaTeX command based on the `samepage` environment to add some explanation below a rule where there should be no page break between the rule and the explanation. However, I would like to have automatic page breaks between such groups of rules and explanations. This does not work yet. I looked for keywords such as "automatic pagebreaks several samepage environments" (and various combinations and modifications thereof), but did not find a solution.

Here is my MNWE that produces an empty page and an overfull page, but should produce two or more pages where as many rule/explanation groups as fit are displayed on the first page and the remaining ones on the next page(s):

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathpartir}

\newcommand{\myrule}[4]{\begin{samepage}\begin{mathpar}\inferrule*[right=(\textsc{#1})]{#2}{#3}\end{mathpar}\begin{center}#4\end{center}\end{samepage}}

\begin{document}

\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}

\end{document}
```

I played around with some simple modifications that did not work: Just adding empty lines between the `\myrule` commands does not change anything. Appending `\\` to the end of the command does not work as it is not allowed there. Appending `\par` instead does not change anything (that was to be expected after the test with empty lines). Appending `\leavevmode\newline` or `\leavevmode\\` to each command only produces an additional empty page after the overfull one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add a legal breakpoint at the end, I used `\goodbreak` here:

As book uses flushbottom, the terms spread out vertically to fill the space, if you want the space at the bottom, use `\raggedbottom`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{mathpartir}

\newcommand{\myrule}[4]{\begin{samepage}\begin{mathpar}%
\inferrule*[right=(\textsc{#1})]{#2}{#3}\end{mathpar}%
\begin{center}#4\end{center}\end{samepage}%
\par\goodbreak}

\begin{document}

\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}
\myrule{name}{premise}{conclusion}{explanation}

\end{document}
```